# Double free or corruption when using a unique_ptr and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory-management, unique-ptr

## Problem:

Crashing with "double free or corruption" when overwriting the `unique_ptr`

## Setup:

I'm working on a calendar app. I am using SFML which has a class `sf::Drawable`.
I have a class `DayView : public sf::Drawable` and a class `WeekView : public sf::Drawable`. 
These two classes are the concrete implementations to display the calendar content. One day-wise one week-wise.
In the class `CalendarScene` I'd like to have a pointer to the current implementation that I can simply replace with a click.
So I place them into an `unique_ptr<sf::Drawable> displayImpl` to automatically delete them on overwrite.

Now I assign the `displayImpl = unique_ptr<WeekView>(new WeekView(...))`
If I now press a button an reassign `displayImpl = unique_ptr<DayView>(new DayView(...))` the application crashes in the (`virtual`) destructor of `WeekView` with the message `*** Error in 
'/home/XXX/workspaces/CDT/XXX/Debug/XXX': double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000000f9ed60 ***`

I also have a `shared_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<Calendar::Entry>>>` as member in either of the `*View` classes. Don't know if this plays a role.

Where lies my problem?

## Code

```
/*
 * CalendarScene.h
 *
 *  Created on: 17. Nov. 2016
 *      Author: martin
 */

#ifndef SCENES_CALENDARSCENE_H_
#define SCENES_CALENDARSCENE_H_

#include "../Scene.h"
#include "../api/google/GoogleApi.h"
#include "../api/Calendar.h"
#include "../event/Event.h"
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class CalendarScene: public Scene {
    public:
        CalendarScene(GoogleApi * api);
        virtual ~CalendarScene();

        void prepare(const sf::Vector2u size) override;
        void event(Event &evt) override;

    private:
        void draw(sf::RenderTarget &, sf::RenderStates) const override;
        sf::String texttodisplay;

        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Calendar>> calendars;
        Calendar::Entries ents;
        Json::Value calendarList;
        Json::Value eventList;

        enum { WEEK, DAY } displayMode;
        int wOffset;

        std::unique_ptr<sf::Drawable> displayImpl = nullptr;

};

#endif /* SCENES_CALENDARSCENE_H_ */
```

---

```
/*
 * CalendarScene.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 17. Nov. 2016
 *      Author: martin
 */

#include "CalendarScene.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include "../ui/SmartText.h"
#include "../ui/UIFactory.h"
#include "../util/sfmladditions.h"

using std::unique_ptr;
using std::shared_ptr;
using std::runtime_error;
using std::time;
using std::time_t;
using std::string;

using io::curl::parameter_map;

using Json::Value;
using Json::ValueIterator;

namespace {

typedef shared_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<Calendar::Entry>>> SharedEntrySharedVector;

enum Format {
    PORTRAIT, LANDSCAPE
};


class WeekView : public sf::Drawable {
public:
    WeekView(SharedEntrySharedVector weekEntries) : ents(weekEntries) {}
    virtual ~WeekView() {}
protected:
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const;
private:
    SharedEntrySharedVector ents;
};

class DayView : public sf::Drawable {
public:
    int dayOffsetToNow = 0;

    DayView(SharedEntrySharedVector dayEnt) : ents(dayEnt) {}

protected:
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates) const;
private:
    SharedEntrySharedVector ents;
};

void WeekView::draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates) const {
    /* some drawing */
}

void DayView::draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates) const {
    /* some other drawing */
}

} // namespace

CalendarScene::CalendarScene(GoogleApi * api) :
        Scene(api), displayMode(WEEK), wOffset(0), displayImpl(new WeekView(SharedEntrySharedVector())) {
}

CalendarScene::~CalendarScene() {
    calendars.clear();
}

/*
 *
 * Obtain calendar list
 * Obtain event list
 *
 */
#include <iostream>
void CalendarScene::prepare(const sf::Vector2u target) {

    /* populating the ents.entries field which is of type vector<shared_ptr<Calendar::Entry>> */

    displayImpl = unique_ptr<WeekView>(new WeekView(SharedEntrySharedVector(&(ents.entries))));
}

void CalendarScene::event(Event &evt) {
    if (evt.type() == Event::Type::ScreenEvent) {
        /* nothing interesting */
    } else if (evt.type() == Event::Type::ButtonEvent) {
        ButtonEvent &b = (ButtonEvent&) evt;
        switch (b.eventChar()) {
        case sf::Keyboard::Key::W:
            displayMode = WEEK;
            displayImpl = unique_ptr<WeekView>(new WeekView(SharedEntrySharedVector(&(ents.entries))));
            break;
        case sf::Keyboard::Key::T:
            displayMode = DAY;
/********  Here lies the problem  ********/
            displayImpl = unique_ptr<DayView>(new DayView(SharedEntrySharedVector(&(ents.entries))));
            break;
        case sf::Keyboard::Key::Right:
            wOffset++;
            break;
        case sf::Keyboard::Key::Left:
            wOffset--;
            break;
        default:
            return;
        }
        if (wOffset < 0)
            wOffset = 0;
        else if (wOffset > 6)
            wOffset = 6;
        if (displayMode == DAY) {
            ((DayView*)displayImpl.get())->dayOffsetToNow = wOffset;
        }
    }
}

void CalendarScene::draw(sf::RenderTarget &target, sf::RenderStates) const {
    if (!displayImpl)
        return;

    target.draw(*displayImpl);
}
```

---

Valgrind says:

```
==27630== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==27630==    at 0x4C2A360: operator delete(void*)
==27630==    by 0x4B6D4D: std::_Sp_counted_ptr<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Calendar::Entry>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Calendar::Entry> > >*, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose()
==27630==    by 0x411665: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release()
==27630==    by 0x41054A: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() 
==27630==    by 0x4ABDC9: std::__shared_ptr<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Calendar::Entry>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Calendar::Entry> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() 
==27630==    by 0x4ABE51: std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Calendar::Entry>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Calendar::Entry> > > >::~shared_ptr()
==27630==    by 0x4A461E: (anonymous namespace)::WeekView::~WeekView() 
==27630==    by 0x4A46B3: (anonymous namespace)::WeekView::~WeekView() 
==27630==    by 0x4AE161: std::default_delete<sf::Drawable>::operator()(sf::Drawable*) const 
==27630==    by 0x4AF7BD: std::unique_ptr<sf::Drawable, std::default_delete<sf::Drawable> >::reset(sf::Drawable*)
==27630==    by 0x4AB181: std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::is_convertible<std::unique_ptr<(anonymous namespace)::DayView, std::default_delete<(anonymous namespace)::DayView> >::pointer, sf::Drawable*>, std::__not_<std::is_array<(anonymous namespace)::DayView> > >::value, std::unique_ptr<sf::Drawable, std::default_delete<sf::Drawable> >&>::type std::unique_ptr<sf::Drawable, std::default_delete<sf::Drawable> >::operator=<(anonymous namespace)::DayView, std::default_delete<(anonymous namespace)::DayView> >(std::unique_ptr<(anonymous namespace)::DayView, std::default_delete<(anonymous namespace)::DayView> >&&) 
==27630==    by 0x4AA445: CalendarScene::event(Event&) 
==27630==    by 0x4DC982: ClientWatch::ClientWatchPrivate::runWindowed() 
==27630==    by 0x4DC6AE: ClientWatch::ClientWatchPrivate::run() 
==27630==    by 0x4DC758: ClientWatch::run()
==27630==    by 0x529CE7: main 
==27630==  Address 0xeb334b0 is 48 bytes inside a block of size 176 alloc'd
==27630==    at 0x4C29180: operator new(unsigned long) 
==27630==    by 0x4E0904: _ZN11ClientWatch18ClientWatchPrivate9makeSceneI13CalendarSceneIRP9GoogleApiEEESt10unique_ptrI5SceneSt14default_deleteIS7_EEDpOT0_ 
==27630==    by 0x4DF88E: _ZN11ClientWatch18ClientWatchPrivate8newSceneI13CalendarSceneIRP9GoogleApiEEEvDpOT0_ 
==27630==    by 0x4DD519: ClientWatch::ClientWatchPrivate::drawFrame() 
==27630==    by 0x4DCB36: ClientWatch::ClientWatchPrivate::runWindowed() 
==27630==    by 0x4DC6AE: ClientWatch::ClientWatchPrivate::run() 
==27630==    by 0x4DC758: ClientWatch::run() 
==27630==    by 0x529CE7: main 
==27630==
```

Changing the `unique_ptr`s to `shared` ones does not help. Still a double free error.

Comment: Your problem is not in the code you showed. Make a [mcve]. Also consider using `std::make_unique`.

Comment: Does SFML have its own ownership scheme?

Comment: @nwp The code is not a MVCE but I tried to redo this from scratch and didn't get the error. So I simply pasted my code... sorry about that, I simply have no clue where the error lies

Comment: could the problem be that I have a `shared_ptr<vector<shared_ptr<Calendar::Entry>>>`. Because in the valgrind stack trace the destructor of the `*View` class calls the destructor of the nested `shared_ptr`s and there appears the probem to be

Answer (score 5):

I believe you might be copying this object and deleting it somewhere else. std::unique_ptr<> should be able to handle the case you mentioned. Take this for example, it works fine:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int a;
    A( int v ) : a(v) {}
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<A> p( new A(1) );
    p = std::unique_ptr<A>( new A(3) );
    std::cout << "A:" << p->a << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Then run

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 testUniquePtr.cpp -o testUniquePtr
$ ./testUniquePtr 
A:3
```

However if you take the pointer and assign to another unique_ptr, like

```
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<A> p( new A(1) );
    std::unique_ptr<A> q( p.get() );
    std::cout << "A:" << p->a << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Then you get a double free:

```
$ ./testUniquePtr 
A:1
*** Error in `./testUniquePtr': double free or corruption (fasttop): 
0x0000000001258c20 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f1ce28367e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7fe0a)[0x7f1ce283ee0a]
```

Comment: I only create new unique_ptrs with new objects to manage... I doubt this is the problem...

Comment: There is a possibility that the corruption is happening somewhere else and not in this specific variable. It is a common distraction. Try to run your application with `valgrind --mem-check=full <cmdline>` and check for earlier errors. Compile with `-o0 -ggdb3` also helps.

Comment: Go loose and replace std::unique_ptr by std::shared_ptr and see what happens. Sometimes when you are stuck any change, even if not particularly rational has the potential to drive you to the solution.

Comment: I totally went loose :-D I did replace them and still have this issue. I'll update the question accordingly in a moment. I also valgrinded it.

Comment: Are there any other messages before this? Is this application multithreaded? Perhaps you should run in debug mode and place a breakpoint or printout at every place this variable is mentioned.  I also dont know much about SFML but perhaps they do like QT and manage the lifetime of their objects internally already so the parent destroys the child.  Try to assign to a simple raw pointer instead and see if it bombs out. If not, check valgrind again to see if there is a leak. Perhaps you are trying to manage an object that is already managed.